# Navigate between .content divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to navigate between .content divs.

Im trying to do this with the code below, but its not working properly.

When I click in the link .next in the last div, all the content disappear instead of go again for the first .content div.

And when I click in the link prev, the content disappear.

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/tebzsuwt/3/

jquery:

```
$(".container div").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
        $(this).hide();
});

$(".btn-next").click(function(){
    if ($(".container div:visible").next().length != 0)
        $(".container div:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).next().fadeIn();
        });
    else {
        $(".divs div:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(".divs div:first").fadeIn();
        });
    }
    return false;
});

$(".btn-prev").click(function(){
    if ($(".container div:visible").prev().length != 0)
        $(".container div:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).prev().fadeIn();
        });
    else {
        $(".container div:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(".container div:last").fadeIn();
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: On clicking `.btn-prev` you want the next one and on clicking `.btn-next` you want the prev one?! Looks like you have mixed up your logic... (btw same for `:first` and `:last`). Provide MCVE remplicating issue, this would make it more clear

Comment: Thanks for notice that, I write this wrong, I will update correctly. I updated with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some minor changes on your code, here is a working example

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <a href="#" class="btn-prev">Prev</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn-next">Next</a>
    <div>   
        <div class="content">
            <p>test 1</p>
            <p>test 2</p>
            <div class="links">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            </div>
        </div>

         <div class="content">
            <p>test 2</p>
            <p>test 3</p>
            <div class="links">
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
        </div>

         <div class="content">
            <p>test 4</p>
            <p>test 5</p>
            <div class="links">
                <a href="#">Link 4</a>
                <a href="#">Link 5</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And JS:

```
$(".container .content").each(function(e) {
    if (e != 0)
        $(this).hide();
});

$(".btn-next").click(function(){
    if ($(".container .content:visible").next().length != 0)
        $(".container .content:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).next().fadeIn();
        });
    else {
        $(".container .content:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(".container .content:first").fadeIn();
        });
    }
    return false;
});

$(".btn-prev").click(function(){
    if ($(".container .content:visible").prev().length != 0) { 
        $(".container .content:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(this).prev().fadeIn();
        });}
    else {
        $(".container .content:visible").fadeOut(function(){
            $(".container .content:last").fadeIn();
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But with your corrections it stils have a issue. If you click in the prev button the .content dont appears. (http://jsfiddle.net/tebzsuwt/7/)

Comment: I made some changes in HTML too, if you don't like that version all you have to do is to wrap your .content divs into another div and everything will be ok

Comment: The problem is that you are using prev() which looks for previous sibling which is h2. You can change that and pass an selector to prev function .prev('.content') and this way the function is looking after previous '.content' class